# Cannot start simple Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using NetBeans 8.1.

I have this simple java Spring Boot project without any beans or persistency.
Two java classes in the same package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSimpleTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSimpleTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And a "index.html" file under src/main/resources->templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run it i have no errors but when i go to **http://localhost:8080/** I have the *Whitelabel Error Page* :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Feb 09 01:53:26 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: can you share your package structure

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies (Maven/Gradle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, whereas `index.html` is a static resource, it belongs under `src/main/resources/static`, not `src/main/resources/templates`.

Second, you don't need a request mapping for static resources. They just work.

So, move `index.html`, delete `WebController`, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You place your html in a wrong directory. It is reason why you get this error.

In Spring Boot project, the default directory store html file to be src/main/webapp. However, it's hard show it with you here. I found this from the tutorial [Spring Boot Maven Example Hello World with JSP](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-maven-example-hello-world.html)

If you create Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf, the default directory is exactly src/main/resources/templates. You can refer to the post [Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-thymeleaf-hello-world-example.html)

I just build project with both of cases, it works normally. Hope this help

Comment: The `src/main/webapp` directory is typically only used for `war` packaging whereas Spring Boot apps are more commonly deployed as `jar` packages. Also the question was not about wars or JSPs. It was about how to get a static `index.html` file to show up.